# EF5 List of one to one dont materialized every entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5.0 CF let's consider theses entities (simplified here):

```
public class Catalog 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PricedProduct> Products { get; set; }    
}

public class PricedProduct 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}

public class Price 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

They are configured with the fluent API :

```
//For the Catalog entity
 ToTable("Catalog", "Catalog");
 this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();

 this.HasMany<PricedProduct>(t => t.Products).WithMany().
 Map(mc =>
        {
        mc.ToTable("CatalogPricedProduct", "Catalog");
        mc.MapLeftKey("PricedProductID");
        mc.MapRightKey("CatalogID");
        });

//For the PricedProduct entity
ToTable("PricedProducts", "Catalog");
HasRequired(t => t.Product).WithOptional().Map(m=>m.MapKey());
HasRequired(t => t.Price).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey());

//For the Product entity
ToTable("Products", "Catalog");
this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();

//For the Price entity
ToTable("Prices", "Catalog");
```

So basically I have a catalog which have n:n relationship with PricedProduct that have two 1:1 relationship with Product and Price

I get those entities  with this linq query :

```
var qy = from cata in this.Set<Catalog>().Include("Products")
                    .Include("Products.Product")
                    .Include("Products.Price")
                    where cata.Name == "name" 
                     select cata;
return qy.FirstOrDefault();
```

Everything works well as long as two PricedProduct does not share the same product or the same price.

Meaning that, in the PricedProducts table the PriceProduct are retrieved and materialized correctly as long as the Product or the Price FK are "unique", if another PricedProduct have the same FK value on price for instance, price wont be loaded in the concerned PricedProduct.

I have quickly check the SQL query generated and it looks fine, it feels like EF fail to materialize two instances of the same object in a same graph ??

Anyone knows what to do or what is wrong with my code ?

thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your understanding of your model is not correct. If multiple `PricedProduct` can have same `Price` or same `Product` you cannot map it as one-to-one relationship but as one-to-many (one price can be assigned to many priced products - same for product). You need:

```
ToTable("PricedProducts", "Catalog");
HasRequired(t => t.Product).WithMany();
HasRequired(t => t.Price).WithMany();
```